# Whys is it a bad idea to have an Object[] array?

Tags: arrays, class, inheritance, object, containers

I was explaining to a friend a few days ago the concept or inheritance and containers.

He has very little programming knowledge so it was really just a friendly chat.
During the conversation he came to me with a question that i just couldn't answer.

"Why cant you just have an array of the top level class, and add anything to it"

I know this is a bad idea having being told so before by someone far smarter but for the life of me i couldn't remember why.

I mean we do it all the time with inheritance.

Say we have class animal which is parent of cat and dog. If we need a container of both of these we make the array of type animal.

So lets say we didn't have that inheritance link, couldn't we just use the base object class and have everything in the one container.

---

No specific programming language.

Comment: It isn't necessarily "bad" (assuming a language like Java), but there may be better approaches -- where "better" generally means more well-typed -- for the given language/problem. As pointed out, `AnimalInterface[]` or `Animal[]` might be better -- but this only works if it's possible to unify the types before `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, there is no problem with this. By declaring an array of a specific type, you are giving implicit information about the contents of that array. You could well declare a contain of `Object` instances, but it means you lose all the type information of the original class at compile-time.

It also means that each time you get an object out of the array at runtime, the only field instances and methods you know exist are the fields/methods of `Object` (which arguably is a compile time problem). To use any of the fields and methods of more specific subclasses of the object, you'd have to cast.

Alternatively, to find out the specific class at runtime you'd have to use features like reflection which are overkill for the majority of cases.

Comment: Not necessarily, and don't forget about RTTI either.

Answer (score 0):

When you take elements out of the container you want to have some guarantees as to what can be done with them. If all elements of the container are returned as instances of `Animal` (remember here that instances of `Dog` are also instances of `Animal`) then you know that they can do all the things that `Animals` can do (which is more things than what all `Objects` can do).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, we do it in programming for the same reason as in Biology? Reptiles and Whales are animals, but they are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation, but without context, it's definitely okay in most (if not all) object-oriented languages to have an array of a base type (that is, as long as they follow all the substitution principles) containing various instances of different derived types.

Answer (score 0):

Object arrays exist in certain cases in most languages. The problem is that whenever you want to use them, you need to remember what type they were, and stay casting them or whatever.

It also makes the code very horrible to follow and even more horrible to extend, not to mention error prone.

```
Plant myplant = new Plant();
listOfAnimals.Add(myplant);
```

would work if the list is object, but you'd get a compile time error if it was Animal.

Comment: I don't really see your point with the Plant example... it's logical that if you try to add a Plant to a collection of Animals, there will be an error, and preferably compile-time.

Comment: Exactly my point. You want that error. If you used an Array of Objects instead it'd fail further down the line, and at runtime.